# Python GUI for real time simulations.

Tags: python, user-interface, drawing, simulation

I am creating the real time simulation of the rays passing throught the system of lenses and mirrors. The parts of the system can be moved by the user and the program calculates new rays.

I have already written a nice module that allows me to rapidly simulate the trajectory of the rays in any system configration. I was using the PIL's ImageDraw module to draw a frame that represents the generated data and wxPython to show the frame and to allow the user interaction.

Unfortunately, the PIL and wxPython combination is very slow (10 fps) . PIL itself is able to draw only 15 frames per second ( I draw the whole frame using only line primitive).

Is there any other way to rapidly draw and show the frame using Python?

Comment: You're probably not happy with this, but have you tried pygame? or pyglet?

Comment: I did not try. Do you think that they will be faster than PIL and wx combination?

Comment: pyglet is good,as @user2033511 mentioned it, and don't forget about pyclutter, which is a big monster, but since it is an optimized and mature C/C++ GUI, maybe it can help you!

Comment: @PiterD I managed to get a stable 100FPS with pyglet (resolution independent) not sure what's behind it to behave that way. And it's not like I measured elaborately :)

Comment: @user2033511 is it possible to draw a frame with Pyglet or I still have to use PIL?

Comment: @PiterD I'm sorry I didn't notice. But what do you mean by frame :o

Comment: @user2033511 I mean, is it possible to draw a screen using pyglet?

Comment: @PiterD If this is about integrating pyglet into a GUI, then yes it's possible (but sometimes tricky). If it's about drawing to a framebuffer, then that's possible as well.